# Python's Scrapy encoding issue

Tags: python, encoding, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape from this site using Scrapy: http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/profile.php?alias=ggonzalez

Here is the function that returns the final item that I am exporting in my spider:

```
def parse_post(self, response):
    theitems = []
    pubs = response.xpath("//div[@id='pubs']/ul/li/a")
    for i in pubs:
        item = FspeopleItem()
        name = str(response.xpath("//div[@id='maincol']/h1/text() | //nobr/text()").extract()).strip()
        pub = str(i.xpath("@title").extract()).strip() 
        item['link'] = response.url
        item['name'] = name
        item['pub'] = pub
        theitems.append(item)
    return theitems
```

For some reason, the returned "theitems" always displays the accented characters (like the í in Díaz) as blank spaces. I cannot figure out why this is. When I open a Scrapy shell and print the info separately from the xpath, it prints to the console fine, but when it comes out of the returned "theitems", it becomes a blank space. I have tested it in both Python2.7 and 3.5.

I am new to Scrapy, encoding in general, and python in general. Everything works, though, except this encoding problem. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you.

///////EDIT////////

Thank you for your suggestions. While the formatting is better in that the /u' stuff is gone when I use the following code (by using

```
.encode("utf-8")
```

and

```
.extract_first()
```

when composing my item), characters with accents are still coming out funky. So, I look at the encoding on the websites from which I am scraping and saw that they are using ISO-8859-1 encoding. So then I tried

```
.encode("ISO-8859-1")
```

when adding components to the item, and this correctly showed the characters with accents, etc. when I opened up the .csv (all the formatting was great). HOWEVER, when I did this, about 25% of all the sites were not scraped - the csv has ~1400 entries instead of ~2100. I can't figure out why it is not scraping some of the sites and not others?

```
import scrapy

from fspeople.items import FspeopleItem

class FSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "hola"
allowed_domains = ["fs.fed.us"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.fs.fed.us/research/people/people_search_results.php?employeename=&keywords=&station_id=SRS&state_id=ALL"]

def __init__(self):
    self.i = 0

def parse(self,response):
    for sel in response.xpath("//a[@title='Click to view their profile ...']/@href"):
        url = response.urljoin(sel.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_post)
    self.i += 1

def parse_post(self, response):
    theitems = []
    pubs = response.xpath("//div[@id='pubs']/ul/li")
    for i in pubs:
        item = FspeopleItem()
        name = response.xpath("//div[@id='maincol']/h1/text() | //nobr/text()").extract_first().strip().encode("ISO-8859-1")
        pubname = i.xpath("a/text()").extract_first().strip().encode("ISO-8859-1")
        pubauth = i.xpath("text()").extract_first().strip().encode("ISO-8859-1")

        item['link'] = response.url
        item['name'] = name
        item['pubname'] = pubname
        item['pubauth'] = pubauth
        theitems.append(item)
    return theitems
```

Comment: When you say "always displays the accented characters", what software are you using to display the output and what output format are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `extract_first()` and `encode()`:

```
for i in pubs:
    item = FspeopleItem()
    name = response.xpath("//div[@id='maincol']/h1/text() | //nobr/text()").extract_first().strip().encode("utf-8")
    pub = i.xpath("@title").extract_first().strip().encode("utf-8") 
    item['link'] = response.url
    item['name'] = name
    item['pub'] = pub
    theitems.append(item)
```

Comment: alecxe, I am still having trouble, though your comment has partially solved the problem. I just made an edit to the bottom of my original post. If the site is "ISO-8859-1", I should use .encode("ISO-8859-1"), right? However, this won't scrape all the entries now. The .encode("uff-8") scrapes all the entries but renders special characters weirdly in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

This is a encode/decode problem.

As Steve said, it could be just the software you are using to see the extracted data.

If it is not that, try to remove the `str()` methods and see what happens. Or maybe change it to `unicode()` [[1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode)]. I usually use none of them, I just let the field be populated with whatever comes from `response.xpath('...').extract()`.

Also, ensure everything is utf8 in your project: the files where you write your code, your settings, and your strings. For example, never write it:

```
item['name'] = 'First name: ' + name
```

Write this (unicode!):

```
item['name'] = u'First name: ' + name
```